# Assembler, save arguments from PSP Dosbox

Tags: parsing, assembly

I have a problem with the following code. I'm working in DOSBOX. Program gets from PSP parameters and saves them into bufor. But it has some bugs and I can't deal with them. Shall someone explain me what I have done incorrectly?

```
dane1   segment
bufor   db  300 dup('$')
ileznakow db 0h
dane1   ends


code1   segment
    ;PSP ->  DS:  80h,  81h,   82h,
    assume  cs:code1, ds:dane1
start1: mov ax,seg top1
    mov ss,ax
    mov sp,offset top1

    MOV AH, 62H                            ;ES wskazuje na segment PSP
    INT 21H
    MOV ES,BX

    mov ax,seg bufor                     ;wstaw do DS:SI adres bufora
    mov ds,ax
    mov si, offset bufor


    MOV al,byte ptr ES:[80H]     ;ustaw ileznakow na liczbe znakow przekazanych w parametrze PSP
    mov [ileznakow], al




    XOR DI,DI                       
    xor cx,cx   
    mov cl, byte ptr ds:[80h]
    sub cx,2
p1: mov al,byte ptr ds:[si]
    mov byte ptr es:[di],al
    inc si
    inc di
    loop    p1 

    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h

code1   ends


stos1   segment stack
    dw  200 dup(?)
top1    dw  ?
stos1   ends


end start1
```

Comment: "it has some bugs" what bugs ? can you describe the expected and actual behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to copy the command line parameters from PSP:82h to dane1:bufor.

When you pass the number 123 to the program you get following values in the PSP:

```
PSP:80h    04h (Length of cammand line)
PSP:81h    20h (ASCII space)
PSP:82h    31h (ASCII 1)
PSP:83h    32h (ASCII 2)
PSP:84h    33h (ASCII 3)
PSP:85h    0Dh (ASCII Carriage Return - CR)
```

You get **always** the first space and the last CR. So you can begin scanning at offset 82h and decrement the value in 80h by 1 (why did you subtract 2?).

You have defined ES to the PSP segment and DS to the data segment. So you have to copy from ES to DS.

```
p1: mov al,byte ptr ds:[si]
    mov byte ptr es:[di],al
```

is **wrong** since you copy from DS to ES.

The loop block (XOR DI,DI...) should look like:

```
    mov di, 82h                 ; SI = pointer to the first character of parameters
    xor cx, cx                  ; Loop counter
    mov cl, byte ptr es:[80h]   ; Number of bytes of the command line (is one to big)
    sub cx, 1                   ; Decrement the number of bytes
p1: mov al,byte ptr es:[di]     ; Load one character from PSP...
    mov byte ptr ds:[si],al     ;     ...and store it in bufor
    inc si                      ; Increment the pointer to bufor
    inc di                      ; Increment the pointer to PSP
    loop p1                     ; Repeat CX times
```